# Sarxos Webcam library

Tags: java, webcam, webcam-capture

I'm trying to access 4 webcams connected via usb. The problem is when I'm direclty connecting the webcams then it's working just fine, but when I'm using a HUB 3.0 in order to connect my webcams then trying to access webcam it's giving me some errors.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException: Cannot execute task
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamProcessor$AtomicProcessor.process(WebcamProcessor.java:72)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamProcessor.process(WebcamProcessor.java:140)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamTask.process(WebcamTask.java:46)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.cgt.WebcamOpenTask.open(WebcamOpenTask.java:20)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.open(Webcam.java:295)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.open(Webcam.java:250)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.open(Webcam.java:236)
    at RunningWebcams.main(RunningWebcams.java:83)
Caused by: com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException: Cannot start native grabber!
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.buildin.WebcamDefaultDevice.open(WebcamDefaultDevice.java:334)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.cgt.WebcamOpenTask.handle(WebcamOpenTask.java:38)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamProcessor$AtomicProcessor.run(WebcamProcessor.java:81)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Code that I'm using is:

```
Webcam webcam1;
Webcam webcam2;
Webcam webcam3;
Webcam webcam4;

webcam1 = Webcam.getWebcams().get(0); // Camera 1
webcam2 = Webcam.getWebcams().get(1); // Camera 2
webcam3 = Webcam.getWebcams().get(2); // Camera 3
webcam4 = Webcam.getWebcams().get(3); // Camera 4

webcam1.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize()); // set size
webcam2.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize()); // set size
webcam3.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize()); // set size
webcam4.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize()); // set size

webcam1.open();
webcam2.open();
webcam3.open();
webcam4.open();
```

Is there a way to solve these error without decreasing the resolution and using a HUB?

Comment: Have you visit the site:
http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder

Comment: Yes, I have. But couldn't find anything tht could help me with this

Comment: Have you downloaded the slf4 related jar file?

Comment: I already dowloaded it. It's working just fine when I'm setting the resolution to QVGA, but I want VGA resolution.